# navigating forward in more pager using f

Tags: ubuntu, cat, text, pager, more

It is given in the man page of `more` that `f` is used to skip forward k screenful of text(default to 1).I saved a very long file using `cat` and used `more` to show it on the screen page by page but when i pressed `f` on the first page itself, it is not navigating forward but it shows `... skipping 29 lines` and then the file closes and the prompt returns.When i try to navigate with `spacebar` it is working properly as expected. As file length is sufficiently long,it should navigate forward by skipping 1 page each time. Why it is showing such a different behviour?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this experiment:

- Open a terminal with 25 rows.
- Run `seq 1 1 100 > test_text`.
- Run `more test_text`.
- Look at the line before last on your screen. It'd say `24`.
- Press <kbd>f</kbd> to **skip** a page.
- Look at the first line on screen. It'd say `49`.

<kbd>f</kbd> skips a page of text. So you saw the first "page" of the file, you pressed <kbd>f</kbd>, and you saw the third page.

At this point, if you press <kbd>f</kbd> again, you'll see `... skipping 24 lines` and the last 4 lines of the file. `more`'ll exit because there are not enough lines to show a fifth page.

Try again using <kbd>space</kbd> instead. <kbd>space</kbd> does not skip pages. You'll see all the pages.

#### Edit

This answer refers to `more version 5.19 (Berkeley 6/29/88), which is currently in use in the Linux community` (see [man more](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html#HISTORY)). As @Kusalananda reports, the result of the "experiment" may vary on different versions/unices.

#### Difference between a `line` and a `row of text on a terminal`

Often these two definitions are interchangeable. In this case, it is important to distinguish them.

- A line is a sequence of characters in a text file that ends with a newline (the `\n` character). `wc -l` command counts the number of lines in a file. The length of a line can be any number between zero and infinite.
- A row of text (on a terminal) is a sequence of characters displayed on a terminal. It has the fixed length of the width of the terminal.

My first "experiment" was too simple, all the lines were (quite for sure) shorter than rows.

In your file, probably, the lines are way longer than rows. To display them, `more` will arrange each line on multiple rows.

Let's try a new experiment:

- Create a file `example` with this content:

  ```
  006 XX\n010 XXYYYY\n015 XXYYYYZZZZZ\n
  ```

  This is a 3 line file. The length of each line is, in the order: 6, 10 and 15 characters. Do not forget to count the space after the number.
- Run `wc -l example`. 3 is the result.
- On a 8 columns terminal, you should see something like

  ```
  006 XX  
  010 XXYY
  YY      
  015 XXYY
  YYZZZZZ
  ```

  The first row is 8 character lenght: `006` + a space + `XX` + 2 spaces.

  The second row is 8 character lenght: `010` + a space + `XXYY`.

  The 3rd row is 8 character lenght: `YY` + 8 spaces.

  Etc etc.

Your 3 lines of text are now 5 rows of text.

The manual page of `more` says:

```
 f         Skip forward k screenfuls of text.  Defaults to 1.
```

This means that `more` will skip so many line of text to fill all the rows of the terminal.

Comment: Hmmm... it's unfortunate that such a basic command is different on different Unices.  On my OpenBSD system, `f` and `Space` (and `^F`) are exactly equivalent according to [the manual](https://man.openbsd.org/more).  I see now that this is different on Linux, which is why I was confused by the question at first.

Comment: @andcoz i am clearly getting what you are trying to say but my doubt still remains.The file i have used with the `more` has almost 5 pages on a 25 row terminal(i checked it by using spacebar) but when i press `f` at the first page it don't show the third page as expected. It shows `... skipping 24 lines`  and then the `more` exits and the prompt returns.In my case i am having five page file even then the `more` is not showing the third page .that's my doubt why it is showing such a behaviour?

Comment: Is your `MORE` environment variable set to some value? Is `more` an alias?

Comment: Can you count the lines in the file using `wc -l filename`? Is it possible that your file have less than 50 lines but that some line are longer than the width of terminal window?

Comment: I checked `echo $MORE` ,it is showing an empty line and `more` is not an alias in my case.when i used `wc -l filename` it is showing 25 lines but how is it possible ? The article from where i copied the text  has around 46 lines .Also i used `cat -n filename` to check number of lines and it is taking whole paragraphs as a single line and it is also showing 25 lines in total . How do i check whether my lines are longer than the width of the terminal window, as long lines fit themselves according to the size of terminal.

Comment: I am getting totally confused , can you tell what part of text is treated as a line on the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

> but it shows `...skipping 29 lines` and then the file closes and the prompt returns

That happens when you press `f` and you reach the end of the document.

For example: You have a file of 40 lines, you do `more myfileof60lines.txt`, it displays the 29 first lines, then you press `f`, so it will skip the 29 next lines, but before that, it reaches the end of the document. So you end up with seeing `...skipping 29 lines`, and the normal behavior of `more` when it reaches the end of the document, which is a return to prompt.

Comment: can you see my comments in the @andcoz's answer, i am having little bit trouble to understand

Comment: Out of the matter, you can use the command `less`. My favourite.